# Find all urls of a certain class until text on page

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm currently building something to look at ebay auctions, but I'm having some difficulty with stopping it from including the items after "More items related to", which I obviously don't want.

Currently, all the links are a standard a href, laid out as

```
<a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah" class="vip" title="x" itemprop="name">
```

class="vip" is in every item link, so that seems like a good thing to use, however it's also in the links to the related items, so I need to not go any further than the more items related to part.

It needs to be regex, because I'm making it with ubot (worked out much quicker than coding in a real language) - sorry for the very noob question, regex isn't my strong suit by any means.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I know you say it has to be a regex, but **don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: If possible, use a kit that provides a DOM along with XPath. That approach is less error prone.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks very much for the comments - unfortunately though, the program's 100% written other than this, which all took a fair while and I really want to avoid redoing. I don't mind changing the regex when the ebay layout gets changed (although hopefully that shouldn't be for a while) - there is literally no way I can use xpath or PHP unfortunately :(

Comment: @Joe We (or I) need a sample of text/html, what you want to match and what not. Also it's mandatory to know the regex flavor.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. I want to match just the URLs themselves, until the point when "More items related to" appears on the page. I'm really sorry about this, but unfortunately I can't find anything mentioning what type of regex it is, although I believe the software is written in C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will:

- match all anchor tags with a `class` attribute of `vip`
- capture `href` attribute values for those anchor tags
- will avoid problematic edge cases
- allow `class` and `href` to appear in the anchor tag in any order
- not capture after the `more to explore` section

`<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"][^\s>]*))(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=['"]?vip['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?>.*?</a>(?=.*?More\sto\sexplore)`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

**Sample Text**

Note the second line has some potentially problematic text

```
<a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-11" class="vip" title="x" itemprop="name">text here</a>
<a onmouseover=' var class="vip"  ; funClassSwap(class); ' href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-22"><form><input type="image" src="submit.gif"></form></a>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-33" title="x" itemprop="name">more text</a>
<div class="seoi-c">
    <h2 class="seoi-h">More to explore</h2>
    <div class="fl">
        <ul class="tso-u">
                <li><a href="http://www.ebay.com/sch/Lathes-/97230/i.html?_dcat=97230&amp;Type=CNC&amp;_trksid=p2045573.m2389" title="Lathes in Metalworking Equipment CNC">Lathes in Metalworking Equipment CNC</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fl">
        <ul class="tso-u">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-44" title="x" itemprop="name">more text</a>
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/<a\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|[^\'"][^\s>]*)) # get the href attribute
(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=[\'"]?vip[\'"]?) # validate the class attribute
(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?> # get the entire tag
.*?<\/a>   # capture the entire anchor tag
(?=.*?More\sto\sexplore)  # validate this match is before the 'more to explore' section
/imsx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-11" class="vip" title="x" itemprop="name">text here</a>
[0][2] = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-11"
[1][0] = <a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-33" title="x" itemprop="name">more text</a>
[1][3] = "http://www.ebay.co.uk/blahblah-33"
```

Comment: On ebay I didn't see the `more items related to` section. So I used the html from ebay showing `more to explore` this `(?=`...`)` positive lookahead requires the more to explore section to appear after the match.

Comment: Your RegEx worked for me but i dont want to get the inner string , is this possible ?

Comment: So you just want to receive the `<a`...`>` portion and not the inner string and trailing `</a>` close tag?

Comment: Then you would remove the `.*?</a>` from the end, see also : http://regexr.com?36ceh

Answer (score 0):

I find that using the "run JavaScript" function is very helpful when it comes to removing unwanted stuff from the page that you do not want to scrape. 
Find the ID or class of the "more items related to" section and then do something like this:

x = document.getElementById("more items id");
    x.remove()

This will remove it from the page. You can then tell the bot to start scraping.